# Reading wrong values from file

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am new to C++ coding. My application requires writing variables to file and then I want to read them again to do some work.

I assign the values to variables and then I dump on the file but when I read the file and check the variable , it has different value assigned to it.
Below are 3 structures which I am using.

```
struct fence_t
{
     uint8_t b:1;
     uint8_t fence_1:2; 
     uint8_t fence_2:2; 
     uint8_t res:3; 
};

struct head_t
{
    uint8_t format; 
    fence_t fence; 
};

struct pack_t
{
    head_t header;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I have assigned format  = 2

```
packet[i].header.format=2;
packet[i].header.fence.b=0;         
packet[i].header.fence.fence_1=2;
packet[i].header.fence.fence_2=2;
packet[i].header.fence.res=0;
```

This is how I open the file and dump data on it. I want values to be written in hex format.

```
f = fopen("packets.txt","w");

fprintf(f, "%04X", packet[i].header);
```

Now in another function I want to read the file.

```
    ff.seekg(0,ios::end);
    size=ff.tellg();
    memblock = new pack_t [size/sizeof(pack_t)];
    ff.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    ff.read((char *)memblock,size);

    void * p = (void *)memblock;    

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        struct q_entry_t t = {i, p};
        queue1.push_back(t);
        p = (void *)((uintptr_t)p+64);
    }
```

When I check the value of format it displays 1.

```
cout<<((head_t *)p)->format<<endl;
```

This is the output of memory window in Visual Studio when I look at the the value of p

0x026A54B8  31 34 30 32 30 30 30 31 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30  140200010100000100

Comment: seems like you are writing as ASCII and trying to read back as binary. What do you want to do?

Comment: Just for clarity, your toolchain did *not* throw up a warning when you did this: `fprintf(f, "%04X", packet[i].header);` ? I.e. sending a `head_t` to a `printf`-family specifier that expects an unsigned integer? Interesting. Head to the C/C++ project properties and turn up your warning level. That should have been detected.

Comment: You would be a lot better off using `fwrite`, which does not expect any sort of formatted input.  You would be even further better off if you familiarized yourself with the C++ way of doing this stuff (even though it's a little harder) instead of the old C way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general if you write with fprintf then read back with fscanf or getline; ie a line / ASCII oriented input mechanism.

If you want the file to be structured binary then write using write and read using read.

Dont mix the two mechanisms up

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

- You pass `packet[i].header` by value in `fprintf()`, and tell `fptrintf()` that's an `int` and that its value should be written in ascii hexadecimal format. Your compiler may pass your value with the size of an `int` and you'll get a usable value. But your compiler might also pass more or less data than an int (because your header is a struct and might be subject to alignment padding), and then, the value that you'll write will not be what you expect.  So it's very implementation dependent.
- By the way, even if your compiler passes a value of appropriate size,  due to endianness, you might have non-portable files.
- Then, you read your data as if it were binary (not opening the file as "rb" would anyway cause havoc).  So you'll read only a part of the ascii data, and interpret the encoding completely differently (i.e. you write '1'  but you'll read 0x31).  That cannot work either.  You have to read it with `fscanf()`, according to the same logic than you write.  But as above, this is very implementation dependent.

As easy alternative, i'd propose you to open the file as binary fstreams, using `ios::binary`,  and use [`write()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/)/[`read()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) to write memory blocks, using the address of your data element and its exact size.

As a more portable alternative, you could use text file streams, and overload `<<` and `>>`  for the type `head_t` to use a well controlled (i.e. fixed byte order) hex format.